# what to use libharu c++ or i text java

Tags: java, c++, pdf, itext, libharu

i need to create pdf creation server and i don't know what is the best tools to chose
java itext engine or c++ libharu , programming is not the problem c++ and java is the same to me .
but i need something that will be fast so c++ libharu is good but iText i know its more rebust and complete .
are those assumption true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a server, I'd go with java, it will be easier to deploy to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create PDFs via Fop from XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use iText will be easier. However, if it will be for heavy use the consumption of memory will be a big problem.

Lib haru is harder to use, but you control the memory and reuse it because it is "c++".